# Схема простого предложения

Tags: синтаксис

Обязательны ли скобки при построении схемы простого предложения?

Comment: @Руслана, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Квадратные скобки указывают на начало и конец предложения, поэтому обязательны. Ну, а в сложном обязательны, чтобы указать на самостоятельность или подчинённость.

Правда, иногда чертят упрощённую схему, без скобок, но это в младших классах и в случаях, когда задают именно упрощённую схему.